# How to append dropdownlist to Html table cell using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML table and a button that allow user to add a new column. Right now user able to add new column when pressing "add". For example a new column `Group1` is added after user press on `add column`. I'm not really sure how to use `createElement`  to achieve my goal. Does anyone have any idea on this issues? thanks .

[image]

**Question**: How can I insert a dropdownlist for every new added column cell instead of `1`, `2`..? Other than that, it should allow user to select and deselect their option.

**Expected Output**:

[image]

```js
let groupNum = 1;
const tableEl = document.getElementById('member_table');

// append column to the HTML table
function appendColumn() {

  // open loop for each row and append cell
  for (let i = 0; i < tableEl.rows.length; i++) {
    createCell(tableEl.rows[i].insertCell(tableEl.rows[i].cells.length), i, 'col');
  }

  tableEl.rows[0].querySelector('td:last-child').textContent = 'Group' + groupNum;
  groupNum++;
}

// create DIV element and append to the table cell
function createCell(cell, text, style) {
  var div = document.createElement('div'), // create DIV element
    txt = document.createTextNode(text); // create text node
  div.appendChild(txt); // append text node to the DIV
  div.setAttribute('class', style); // set DIV class attribute
  div.setAttribute('className', style); // set DIV class attribute for IE (?!)
  cell.appendChild(div); // append DIV to the table cell
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table id="member_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="javascript:appendColumn()">Add column</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create function `createSelectEl` which will take `values` for option and return `select` element with options. While calling `createCell` instead of passing `i` value pass this newly generated `select` element.

In `createCell` instead of creating textNode just append the passed select element.

```js
function createSelectEl(values){
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    select.name = "group1";
    select.id = "groupId"
    // 1st option
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = 'Select One';
    select.appendChild(option);
    for (const val of values)
    {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = val;
        option.text = val;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
    return select;
}

let groupNum = 1;
const tableEl = document.getElementById('member_table');

// append column to the HTML table
function appendColumn() {

  // open loop for each row and append cell
  for (let i = 0; i < tableEl.rows.length; i++) {
    const values = ["3540531", "3518796", "4512365", "1234896"];
    createCell(tableEl.rows[i].insertCell(tableEl.rows[i].cells.length), createSelectEl(values), 'col');
    // createCell(tableEl.rows[i].insertCell(tableEl.rows[i].cells.length), i, 'col');
  }

  tableEl.rows[0].querySelector('td:last-child').textContent = 'Group' + groupNum;
  groupNum++;
}

// create DIV element and append to the table cell
function createCell(cell, text, style) {
  var div = document.createElement('div'); // create DIV element
    //txt = document.createTextNode(text); // create text node
  // div.appendChild(txt); // append text node to the DIV
  div.appendChild(text);
  div.setAttribute('class', style); // set DIV class attribute
  div.setAttribute('className', style); // set DIV class attribute for IE (?!)
  cell.appendChild(div); // append DIV to the table cell
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table id="member_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="javascript:appendColumn()">Add column</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the minimal version of what you need. You can update/replace you create cell function with the following template (with your requirement).

```
function createDropdown(cell) {
    var select = document.createElement('select');
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value =  i;
    option.text = "Option " + i;
    select.appendChild(option);
  }
    cell.appendChild(select);
}
```

You can read about any JavaScript functions (like `createElement`) on Mozilla firefox documentations.
Google: `keyword mdn` e.g. `createElement mdn`